# docker-compose don't load additional env-file defined in yaml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i get crazy with the env_file setting inside my docker-compose.yml.
when i name the file `.env` and put it in the root of my project everything works fine. the main point of having this env file was to have multiple enviroments (dev, staging, production) where i made my settings.
as soon i name my file different (for example `dev.env` and put it inside a env folder) and try to load it inside my docker-compose file it won't work.

i make a simple example to make things clear.
for simplicity i use one variable DC_DOCKERFILE where i define what dockerfile to load.

file: `.env` in the root folder:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=test
DC_DOCKERFILE=./Dockerfile.bash.dev
```

file: `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  bash:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ${DC_DOCKERFILE}
```

and `docker-compose config` shows everything is cool and build works as well:

```
networks: {}
services:
  bash:
    build:
      context: /devops/myproject
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.bash.dev
version: '2.0'
volumes: {}
```

now the point which freaks me out:

- create a folder env in the root of the project
- move .env to ./env/dev.env
- add `env_file: ./env/dev.env` inside my docker-compose.yml

env content looks same like above so i don't post the content again.

my new `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:

  bash:
    env_file: ./env/dev.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ${DC_DOCKERFILE}
```

only change, add the env_file settings.

and now i `docker-compose config` gives me this:

```
networks: {}
services:
  bash:
    build:
      context: /devops/myproject
      dockerfile: ''
    environment:
      COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: test
      DC_DOCKERFILE: ./Dockerfile.bash.dev
version: '2.0'
volumes: {}
```

say what? where the hack is my dockerfile settings?

of course `docker-compose build` don't like that too and bothers with:

```
docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache                                                                                 
WARNING: The DC_DOCKERFILE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building bash
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

the variables get loaded but somehow not assigned.
so i don't get it.
am i maybe wrong and i can't use the env file for docker-compose stuff inside the docker-compose.yml file. would make sence that it need to be loaded first somehow via docker-compose parameter or something but after i spend so much time i want to know if i can load it inside or not :)

thanks for help and hell yeah for open source and the awesome community.

peace out

Answer (score 2):

When `.env` *file* is present in the folder docker-compose command is executed, those environment variables are used as environment variables for docker-compose execution and variable substitution. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

However when you define `env_file` option to your service, the service will get those variables from the file as environment variables and those are not used for variable substitution.

Comment: hi lauri, thanks for your answer. does this mean i can only have one env file to do what i need, right? so how do people handle different environments with best practices? i could make my variables dynamic and set them depending on a shell env or whatever, but just want to learn the docker way in doing things right. thanks

Comment: Yes, based on the documentation you can have only one env file.